# Django Rest Registration (3rd party package) asking for signature to verify registration.. What signature?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using 'django rest registration' and when I create a new user everything works fine. The issue is that the 'verify-registration' endpoint requires a user_id, timestamp and a signature and I have no idea what timestamp and signature I'm supposed to post to the endpoint. [The documentation](https://django-rest-registration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detailed_configuration/register.html#verify-registration) is not really giving me any clues. Can anyone tell me what exact signature this 'verify-registration' endpoint is asking to have posted to it please?

Here's the piece from the docs:

> and then it should perform AJAX request to https://backend-host/api/v1/accounts/verify-registration/ via HTTP POST with following JSON payload:

```
{
    "user_id": "<user id>",
    "timestamp": "<timestamp>",
    "signature": "<signature>"
}
```

[image]

Edit: This is what I need to post to the verify-registration endpoint, I know the user_id and I can create a timestamp but how do I get the signature to post to this endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Based of its documentaton on this [link](https://django-rest-registration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detailed_configuration/register.html#verification-workflow) an email send to registered user on that li nk you will see this args.
To get email in development add
`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`
In settings.py and you will see email in console.

Comment: I need to know what the signature is that needs to be posted to the endpoint. My project has email already.

Comment: Assuming the registration was correct, The register endpoint will generate an e-mail which will contain an URL which the newly registered user should click to activate his/her account. the URL would be in a form:

https://frontend-host/verify-user/?user_id=<user id>&timestamp=<timestamp>&signature=<signature>

Comment: If want to now how signature create check github code from this [link](https://github.com/apragacz/django-rest-registration/blob/master/rest_registration/utils/signers.py)